# insert statement is adding nulls when i have data

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have 10 tables design1, design2, ect... 
I'm doing an insert into statement into an 11th table that will hold all the info from the previous 10.

```
Insert into Total_Design select * from Design1
```

After executing this it populate Total_Design with all variables accept for 5 columns that instead of being filled are filled with nulls.

The 5 columns are type bit and contain either 0 or 1 in them. 
I then attempted to make those 5 columns to not accept nulls at which point it throws the error.

Cannot insert the value Null into column  x, Table Total_Design; column does not allow nulls. Insert fails.

Like i said Design1 has information in these columns, Total_Design is just not accepting it.

Comment: You need to specify the *order* of the columns you're inserting.  If the two table's column structure are different, you're going to be inserting things in the wrong places.

Comment: Can you either post a minimal example showing this, or even better create a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: just specify which columns you are going to select into and which you select. Also great for maintainability later on.

Comment: You should always specify the columns on an insert and avoid the use of select * (unless it is a count or an exists)

Comment: @Siyual So even if all column names are the same if some are out of order it wont correctly work?. and if so Ive never ordered my columns before where would i add the order too? would instead of select * i would just select ( list all columns here in correct order for Total_Design)?

Comment: @Himarm Correct.  If you do `Insert Table Select *` it will insert based on the ordinal.  You'll need to do something like `Insert Total_Design (Col1, Col2, Col3) Select Col1, Col2, Col3 From Design1`

Comment: @Siyual Thanks i believe thats my problems im working with Old tables trying to make a new concise table, but the old 10 are all in different orders for some crazy reason.

Comment: The different orders on the tables is one of many reasons you should specify the columns in your insert and in the select. When you don't specify them the sql engine will try to insert in the order the columns are in each table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
INSERT INTO Total_Design (Column1, Column2, Column3) 
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Design1
```

Comment: with this if i have columns out of order i would just do something like   
Insert Into Total_Design(column1, Column3, Column8, Column2) ect in the order i need?

Comment: You want to have the same columns in the same order from the two tables in the query